# How to get results in View from 3 tables in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have 3 Related tables, Table1 => Table2 => Table3 Relationship is as this type.

I have data from Table1 and Table2 because i have model to show from Table1, now my problem is Table3, i cant get data to show.
I need to show data in  details, and my project is for Polls.

1. Table1 = Questions (Key is QID)
2. Table2 = Answers options (key ANID, and q_ID is key to Questions)
3. Table3 = Results(Count voting) (key is RID, and ans_ID is key to AnswerOption)

Controller is Default Code:

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }



            Questions questions= db.Questions.Find(id);
            if (questions== null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }




            return View(questions);
        }
```

VIEW Code:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Answers)
        {

            if (item != null)
            {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.AnswerName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Results.Result)
            </td>

        </tr>
            }
```

MODEL QUESTIONS:

```
public class Questions
    {
        public Questions()
        {
            Answers= new HashSet<Answers>();

        }
        [Key]
        public  int QID { get; set; }
        public string Prasanje { get; set; }
        public bool pubOdg { get; set; }
        public int? avtor { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Answers> Answers { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("avtor")]
        public virtual tbl_useri tbl_useri { get; set; }

    }
```

MODEL ANSWERS:

```
 public Answers()
        {
            Results= new HashSet<Results>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int ANID{ get; set; }

        public int q_ID{ get; set; }


        public string Odgovor { get; set; }
        public string kreator { get; set; }
        public int? rCount { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("q_ID")]
        public virtual Questions Questions{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Results> Results{ get; set; }
```

MODEL RESULTS:

```
 public class Results
    {
        [Key]
        public int RID{ get; set; }
        public int ans_ID{ get; set; }
        public int Result{ get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("ans_ID")]
        public virtual Answers Answers { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Tip: Don't use EF entity objects as ViewModels.

Comment: You use Entity Framework to call `db.Questions` which will build the question entity based on the id provided.  Does that entity have access to answers?  Did Entity Framework actually build that sub object?

Comment: Because i`m junior in MVC, can you help me for  better solution ?

Comment: Can you post all your model here?

Comment: This question is soooo far from complete and there are so many ways to do this (MVC, MVVM patterns, repository, UoW) I don't think this can currently be answered, and potentially not well ever, as attempting to answer it will expose where the code is missing other major shortcomings in understanding (EF joins, unions, cross apply, automapper, ...)

Comment: I Updated Question with models

Comment: Some advice for research, Entity Framework is powerful but you define the context so it can map to your entity.  But the front-end or view data does not often represent a entity or data aggregate, so more often than not you need to map or expand how you translate the data to the front-end view.

Comment: @Hien Nguyen The models is posted in a Question. Do you have solution?

Comment: Can you attach the screen do you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'll begin with some definitions:

- A **view-model** is a type that represents data specific to a particular rendered view. The controller action should create this object and fill it with loaded data then pass it to the view.

  - This is at the heart of separation-of-concerns in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core and is a common design pattern in all modern (post-2005) web-programming frameworks.
  - Compare it to the old-school PHP/CGI/Classic ASP programming where you'd mix database code with HTML.
  - In web programming, a View-Model is generally a **non-observable, immutable and ephemeral** object that only lasts for the life of the HTTP request. Whereas in desktop programming (like WPF, UWP XAML, etc) a view-model is generally **observable, mutable and long-lived**).
- A **model** class (distinct from a **view-model**) or **entity** class is an object that represents data from your backing-store database. (Ignore the fact that Razor uses the keyword `@model` to denote the view-model).

(I'm disappointed and annoyed that most beginner-level tutorials for ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core still introduce users to the anti-pattern of using Entity Framework entity types as view-models. These tutorials should teach readers to use separate view-models to avoid leading readers down the wrong path and eventual confusion like this OP is. Using EF entities as view-models also leads to security issues as it allows a malicious user to reset other users' passwords (for example) if there's inadequate validation of input requests (which is what `[BindNever]` is for, for example). My point is: **just don't**.)

Back on-topic:

If this is a one-way view (i.e. you're only showing data from your database without allowing the user to edit that data in a `<form>`) then define a new class as your view-model and populate it with your entity data as properties.

In your case, your controller action is `QuestionsController::Details`, so I'd have this:

```
public class DetailsViewModel
{
    // One-way members:

    [BindNever]
    public String PageTitle { get; internal set; }

    public Question TheQuestion  { get; internal set; }

    public List<Answer> TheAnswers { get; internal set; }

    // Two-way members:

    // (you don't have any forms, so this area is empty)
}
```

Then modify your controller action to create, populate and return this view-model type:

```
public async IActionResult Details(Int32? id)
{
    if( id == null ) return this.NotFound();

    Question question = await this.db.Questions.SingleOrDefaultAsync( id.Value );
    if( question == null ) return this.NotFound();

    DetailsViewModel vm = new DetailsViewModel()
    {
        PageTitle = "Details for " + question.Title,
        TheQuestion = question,
        TheAnswers = await this.db.Answers.Where( q => a.Question == question ).ToListAsync()
    };

    return this.View( model: vm );
}
```

And change your Razor view to use this view-model:

```
@model DetailsViewModel

<html>
<head>
<title>@Model.PageTitle</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Question</h2>

<p>@Model.TheQuestion.QuestionText</p>

<h2>Answers</h2>

@foreach( Answer ans in this.Model.TheAnswers )
{
<h3>Answer @ans.Name</h3>

    @foreach( Result result in ans.Results )
    {
<h3>@result.Name</h3>
    }
}

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to allow users to edit data in a `POST` in a `<form>` then you will need to essentially define new classes for each table row you want users to be able to edit. But that's beyond the scope of your original question, but search online for "ASP.NET mvc model binding" for more details.